# Add new field to SOLR with default value. Populate existing documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I have added a new field to a SOLR 3.6.1 schema.xml with a default value. Is it possible to populate / index existing documents in the SOLR repository with this default value without having to re-load all the data? I have been looking at re-indexing and re-optimizing but haven't been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Any changes in schema.xml related to addition or change in fields would need re-indexing of the data.
So you have to reload your data.

If you know the document, you can do a [Partial update of all those document](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/) with just that field.

Comment: Please note that partial update support is only available in Solr 4.0, so you would need to update the Solr instance to take advantage of that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Solr: Add new fields with Default Value for Existing Documents](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/06/solr-use-doctransformer-to-change.html)

If we only need search and display the new fields, we can do the following steps.

1. add the new field definition in schema.xml:
2. We need update search query: when search default value for this newFiled, also search null value: 
   -(-newFiled:defaultValue AND newFiled:[* TO *])
3. Use DocTransformer to add default value when there is no value in that field for old data.

Some functions may not work such as sort, stats.